# Diminuir tamanho do navbar ao rolar

Tags: materialize

Preciso diminuir o tamanho da navbar quando o usuário rolar a tela mas manter a tab com o feito pra você, pizzas salgadas..., estou usando o materialize e estou com dificuldades.

```
.altura{
    padding-bottom: 79px;
}

<div class="navbar-fixed">  
                <nav class="yellow lighten-4" id="navbartamanho">
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <!-- Logo para PC -->
                        <a href="#" class="brand-logo left">
                            <div class="hide-on-med-and-down">
                                <img src="img/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Logo">
                            </div>  
                        </a>

                        <!-- Logo para Tablet / Celular -->
                        <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">
                            <div class="hide-on-large-only">
                                <img src="img/logo.png" id="logo2" alt="Logo2">
                            </div>  
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger" id="botaoaba"><i class="material-icons black-text">menu</i></a>

                        <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down" id="abas">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#modal1" class="modal-trigger black-text">                     
                                    <i class="material-icons left">account_circle</i>
                                    Logar/Cadastrar
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#modal4" class="modal-trigger black-text">
                                    <i class="material-icons left">account_circle</i>
                                    Minha Conta
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#modal2" class="modal-trigger black-text">                     
                                    <i class="material-icons left">contact_mail</i>
                                    Dom Delivery
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#modal3" class="modal-trigger black-text">                         
                                <i class="material-icons left">contact_phone</i>
                                    Fale Conosco
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="right" id="carrinho">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons left black-text">shopping_cart</i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="nav-content">
                                <ul class="tabs z-depth-5">
                                    <div class="col l2 m2 amber lighten-5" data-ref="pravoce">
                                        <li class="tab">
                                            <a class="black-text" href="#feitopravoce">
                                                <b>Feito Pra Você</b>                               
                                            </a>                                            
                                        </li>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="col l2 m2 amber">
                                        <li class="tab">
                                            <a class="white-text" href="#pizzasalgada">
                                                <b>Pizzas Salgadas</b>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="col l2 m2 light-green lighten-2">   
                                        <li class="tab">
                                            <a class="white-text" href="#">
                                                <b>Pizzas Doces</b>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="col l2 m2 green darken-3">      
                                        <li class="tab">
                                            <a class="white-text" href="#">
                                                <b>Esfihas</b>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="col l2 m2 pink lighten-2">
                                        <li class="tab">
                                            <a class="white-text" href="#">
                                                <b>Hamburgueres</b>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="col l2 m2 cyan lighten-1">
                                        <li class="tab">
                                            <a class="white-text" href="#">
                                                <b>Bebidas</b>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>   
                                    </div>                                    
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>      
                </nav>
            </div>
```